# Casting &[u8] to std::io::Read causes Sized issue

Tags: casting, rust, traits

Trying to provide `&[u8]` as argument to a function requiring `Read` doesn't seem to work as I expected, as illustrated by the below example.

```
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let bytes: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3, 4];
    print_reader(&bytes);
}

fn print_reader(reader: &(Read + Sized)) {
    for byte in reader.bytes() {
        println!("{}", byte.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error: the trait bound `std::io::Read + Sized: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
 --> <anon>:9:24
9 |>     for byte in reader.bytes() {
  |>                        ^^^^^
note: `std::io::Read + Sized` does not have a constant size known at compile-time

error: the trait bound `std::io::Read + Sized: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
 --> <anon>:9:5
9 |>     for byte in reader.bytes() {
  |>     ^
note: `std::io::Read + Sized` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::io::Bytes<std::io::Read + Sized>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1acf98e0081dbd9ebac04eef7b7d23d7&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The following trait implementation can be found in the [`std::slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) documentation:

`impl<'a> Read for &'a [u8]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is a rather an unhelpful error message. I'll try to explain:

---

**First**: you can't have a trait object `&Sized`. This violates the [first object safety rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#the-trait-cannot-require-self-sized) and it doesn't really make sense either. The only reason to add the `Sized` trait bound is to use the special property of all `Sized` types (e.g. saving it on the stack). Look at this example trying to use the property:

```
fn foo(x: &Sized) {
    let y = *x;
}
```

What size would `y` have? The compiler can't know, as with any other trait object. So we're not able to use the only purpose of `Sized` with trait objects. Thus a trait object `&Sized` is useless and can't really exist.

In this case the error message at least kind of tells us the correct thing:

```
error: the trait `std::marker::Sized` cannot be made into an object [--explain E0038]
 --> <anon>:7:1
7 |> fn foo(x: &Sized) {
  |> ^
note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

---

**Furthermore**: I suspect you added the `+ Sized` bound to work around the same error, which already showed up when you had the argument `reader: &Read`. Here is one important insight from the detailed error description:

> Generally, `Self : Sized` is used to indicate that the trait should not be used as a trait object.

This restriction for `Read::bytes` does make sense, because the `Bytes` iterator calls `Read::read()` once for every single byte. If this function call would be a virtual/dynamic one, the overhead for the function call would be much higher than the actual process of `read`ing the byte.

---

**So...** why do you need to have `Read` as a trait object anyway? Often it's sufficient (and in any case much faster) to handle this via generics:

```
fn print_reader<R: Read>(reader: R) {
    for byte in reader.bytes() {
        println!("{}", byte.unwrap());
    }
}
```

This avoids dynamic dispatch and works nicely with the type checker *and* the optimizer.